# How to see system wide hard disk disk free with a GUI tool?

Tags: filesystems, hard-disk, disk-usage, disk, gui

First of all, I'm a Linux User and know that df and tons of other CLI tools exist. I'm only looking for a GUI tool, this makes this question relevant, so please don't mention CLI tools.

In the GUI arena, we do have tons and tons of disk analyzer tools. They don't work for me, what I need is a simple OVERVIEW over all media that is attached to my system and be able to use a GUI, basically what df does, but with a visual usage bar. Windows does this well, as the pic below shows and I raked my brain and the Internet to find such a tool and so far, zero.

The disk analyzer (where is your space used) are overkill and do not allow to show the total for several disks. Also, I don't want a tool to bog down the system, when a simple check for disk space totals is enough.

[image: windows disk free system wide]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both GNOME Disks and GNOME System Monitor on my Ubuntu provide this:

- GNOME System Monitor:

  [image: File Systems tab]
- GNOME Disks:

  [image: Partition view]

  The theme makes the view a bit unclear, but the darker orange part shows the occupied space.

Comment: Cool, that definitely works. You can see that I'm a KDE user by never having seen gnome system monitor. ;-)

Comment: I still use the tool you guys recommended, very nice to use and visual.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to set up a [Conky](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky) theme that shows current disk usage. This way you can keep an eye on it all the time. I have an [i3-bar status](https://www.reddit.com/r/unixporn/comments/86ih0a/i3gaps_custom_bash_prompt_compton_and_termite/?st=jfdjuai4&sh=345bb75b) showing the usage on my two main drives.